# Load Balancing in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

I am making a project for the university. When admission Starts, suddenly a lot of traffic comes at my site around 50000 to 100000 users. Site goes down therefore. How to manage it Please provide me details regarding this.

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There are several different things you should look at:

- ASP.NET Caching

Do you have a caching strategy? There are a lot of features in ASP.NET that will allow you to optimize how the server responds to requests. Take a look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c(v=VS.100).aspx

- Load Balancing is really applied by the web server, not the server framework (ASP.NET / etc). If general opimizations and caching still give you problems, look into load balancing and web farms for IIS. Take a look at:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/213/network-load-balancing/

- If you have a lot of money, there are hardware solutions for load balancing that work with IIS. That's outside the provinces of programming and StackOverflow but it's helpful to know they are out there especially if you need to have a discussion with management about the pros and cons (expense!!) of which route to take.